# How to copy thread shared array variable to normal array

Tags: arrays, multithreading, perl, perl-module

I have a shared array which stores objects.

```
package A;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
our @LISTS;
share(@LISTS);
use B;

my $obj = B->new();
my $shared_test = shared_clone($obj);
push(@A::LISTS, $shared_test);
```

I want to copy LISTS shared array to normal array.

I copied it into two arrays in another module and when i modified one array it is effecting to another array.
Here is the code

```
my @test1 = @A::LISTS;
my @test2 = @A::LISTS;
$test1[0]->set_value("1");
print "value: ".$test1[0]->get_value()."\n";
$test2[0]->set_value("2");
print "value2: ".$test2[0]->get_value()."\n";
print "value1: ".$test1[0]->get_value()."\n";
```

Output:

```
value: 1
value2: 2
value1: 2
```

But i want @test1, @test2 arrays come out from shared. How can i do it?

I want output like

```
value: 1
value2: 2
value1: 1
```

Modified value should not effect to another array

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give expected output. edited post with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, sharing is a red herring.  You'll see the same behavior if you omit it.

The elements of `@A::LISTS` are blessed references, and so are the elements in your copies of the array.  So, `$A::LISTS[0]` points to some location in memory, and your copy in `$test1[0]` points to the same location — in other words, they hold the same object.

You'll need to make explicitly separate copies of your objects to achieve what you want:

```
use Clone qw(clone);

my @copies = map { clone($_) } @A::LISTS;
```

Comment: Here i can not access $copies[0]->get_value(); value because it is storing into map.